# Android Studio Error Message: Use Of Undeclared Identifier 'accept4'

Tags: android, c++, gradle, java-native-interface, .so

the **jni folder** not appear in **android studio** and after build only **java folder get build**.

[image: MAIN FOLDER FROM EXPLORER]

[image: MAIN FOLDER FROM ANDROID STUDIO]

as you can see the **jni folder** appear in **explorer** but not inside **android studio**.

EDIT:
so after i added this in my build.gradle

```
externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {

        path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'

    }
}
```

the **jni folder** appered as **cpp folder name**
but when i compile i get **this error from **SocketServer.cpp**:**

> **use of undeclared identifier 'accept4'**

This is the code :

```
bool SocketServer::Accept() {
    if ((acceptfd = accept4(listenfd, nullptr, nullptr, SOCK_CLOEXEC)) < 0) {
        Close();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and **headers** is already **includes**:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
```

Comment: Is the option available to "Add C/C++ Nature"?

Comment: _"this is the source code i want to compile on github"_. Questions should be self-contained. Put the relevant code in the question itself. _"use of undeclared identifier 'accept4'"_. Sounds like you might be building for a really old Android version.

Comment: Michael   minSdkVersion 14 , targetSdkVersion 29 ,  compileSdkVersion 29

Comment: sdk version 14 is Android 4.0, which is ten years old at this point.

Comment: @Botje i already changed to sdk 29 but error remains "use of undeclared identifier 'accept4'

" is the error from the ndk version or what because android studio cant find the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i get **pass the error** "`use of undeclared identifier 'accept4'`" by setting these :

```
from compileSdkVersion 29       to compileSdkVersion 30
from buildToolsVersion "29.0.3" to buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
from minSdkVersion 21           to minSdkVersion 22
from targetSdkVersion 29        to targetSdkVersion 30
```